# Can't install speechrecognition and pyttsx3 on Mac

Tags: python

I'm using 3.8.1, macOS Catalina 10.15.5, I'm new in Python, I tried use pip install speechrecognition and pyttsx3 but it's doesn't work. I tried install pyaudio too but it have a fault.

```
125:~ quan$ pip install speechrecognition
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: speechrecognition in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (3.8.1)

125:~ quan$ pip install PyAudio
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
  Building wheel for PyAudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dv/_f33qv0x0j16djzj64q5c6hh0000gn/T/pip-install-7DfK8S/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dv/_f33qv0x0j16djzj64q5c6hh0000gn/T/pip-install-7DfK8S/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/dv/_f33qv0x0j16djzj64q5c6hh0000gn/T/pip-wheel-p9cG4j
       cwd: /private/var/folders/dv/_f33qv0x0j16djzj64q5c6hh0000gn/T/pip-install-7DfK8S/PyAudio/
  Complete output (16 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7
  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/src
  cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -iwithsysroot /usr/local/libressl/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -pipe -DMACOSX=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
  src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
  #include "portaudio.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
  Running setup.py clean for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dv/_f33qv0x0j16djzj64q5c6hh0000gn/T/pip-install-7DfK8S/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dv/_f33qv0x0j16djzj64q5c6hh0000gn/T/pip-install-7DfK8S/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/dv/_f33qv0x0j16djzj64q5c6hh0000gn/T/pip-record-XU4eyt/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/quan/Library/Python/2.7/include/python2.7/PyAudio
         cwd: /private/var/folders/dv/_f33qv0x0j16djzj64q5c6hh0000gn/T/pip-install-7DfK8S/PyAudio/
    Complete output (16 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/src
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -iwithsysroot /usr/local/libressl/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -pipe -DMACOSX=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
    #include "portaudio.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dv/_f33qv0x0j16djzj64q5c6hh0000gn/T/pip-install-7DfK8S/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dv/_f33qv0x0j16djzj64q5c6hh0000gn/T/pip-install-7DfK8S/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/dv/_f33qv0x0j16djzj64q5c6hh0000gn/T/pip-record-XU4eyt/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/quan/Library/Python/2.7/include/python2.7/PyAudio Check the logs for full command output.



125:~ quan$ pip  install pyttsx3
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pyttsx3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc>=2.4 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-ColorSync==5.3; platform_release >= "17.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Quartz==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-MediaAccessibility==5.3; platform_release >= "13.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-VideoSubscriberAccount==5.3; platform_release >= "18.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CoreBluetooth==5.3; platform_release >= "14.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==5.3; platform_release >= "9.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-ImageCaptureCore==5.3; platform_release >= "10.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-ExternalAccessory==5.3; platform_release >= "17.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-AVFoundation==5.3; platform_release >= "11.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-StoreKit==5.3; platform_release >= "11.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Network==5.3; platform_release >= "18.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-NotificationCenter==5.3; platform_release >= "14.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-MapKit==5.3; platform_release >= "13.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CoreAudio==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-GameController==5.3; platform_release >= "13.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Social==5.3; platform_release >= "12.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CoreSpotlight==5.3; platform_release >= "17.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-AVKit==5.3; platform_release >= "13.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-SecurityFoundation==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-FinderSync==5.3; platform_release >= "14.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-MediaPlayer==5.3; platform_release >= "16.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-ContactsUI==5.3; platform_release >= "15.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-SceneKit==5.3; platform_release >= "11.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-DVDPlayback==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-PhotosUI==5.3; platform_release >= "15.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==5.3; platform_release >= "9.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-AdSupport==5.3; platform_release >= "18.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CoreServices==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-SecurityInterface==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-MultipeerConnectivity==5.3; platform_release >= "14.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-WebKit==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-NaturalLanguage==5.3; platform_release >= "18.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-MediaToolbox==5.3; platform_release >= "13.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-LocalAuthentication==5.3; platform_release >= "14.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CoreMediaIO==5.3; platform_release >= "11.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-GameKit==5.3; platform_release >= "12.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-UserNotifications==5.3; platform_release >= "18.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Automator==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CloudKit==5.3; platform_release >= "14.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==5.3; platform_release >= "10.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Security==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Vision==5.3; platform_release >= "17.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==5.3; platform_release >= "10.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==5.3; platform_release >= "9.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-ApplicationServices==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-EventKit==5.3; platform_release >= "12.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==5.3; platform_release >= "10.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CalendarStore==5.3; platform_release >= "9.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-GameplayKit==5.3; platform_release >= "15.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-NetworkExtension==5.3; platform_release >= "15.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CoreAudioKit==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-VideoToolbox==5.3; platform_release >= "12.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CoreMedia==5.3; platform_release >= "11.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==5.3; platform_release >= "9.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-NetFS==5.3; platform_release >= "10.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-MediaLibrary==5.3; platform_release >= "13.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-IMServicePlugIn==5.3; platform_release >= "11.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-PubSub==5.3; platform_release >= "9.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN==5.3; platform_release >= "10.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-DiscRecordingUI==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Intents==5.3; platform_release >= "16.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-libdispatch==5.3; platform_release >= "12.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CryptoTokenKit==5.3; platform_release >= "14.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-OSAKit==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Accounts==5.3; platform_release >= "12.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==5.3; platform_release >= "9.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-DiskArbitration==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==5.3; platform_release >= "9.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-iTunesLibrary==5.3; platform_release >= "10.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==5.3; platform_release >= "10.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CoreText==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-SafariServices==5.3; platform_release >= "15.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-ModelIO==5.3; platform_release >= "15.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-IOSurface==5.3; platform_release >= "10.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-BusinessChat==5.3; platform_release >= "18.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CoreML==5.3; platform_release >= "17.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-CoreData==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-core==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-SpriteKit==5.3; platform_release >= "13.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Contacts==5.3; platform_release >= "15.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-GameCenter==5.3; platform_release >= "12.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Photos==5.3; platform_release >= "15.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-QTKit==5.3; platform_release >= "9.0" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3) (5.3)
125:~ quan$
```

Comment: It looks like you are using Python 2.7, not 3.8.1. Installer tries to compile library, but it lacks header files. I tried to install it on Python 3.7 and 3.8 and it worked fine.

Comment: yah, I found a simle way that's pip3 instead for pip